# Is there any way to convert event emitted by child component using @output into observable stream in parent

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6, rxjs-observables

To emit any click from child to parent we can make use of @output in the child and in parent html we can listen to that event using the way shown below

**<app-item-output (newItemEvent)="addItem($event)">**

in parent we can write method **addItem($event)** and do our work but is there any way to convert it into stream so that i can use it in combination with other observable.

One way I can think of now is having a subject in parent and then emitting a value like below to create a stream in parent

```
addItem($event) {
subject.emit()
}
```

But if we have any direct way to convert the event emitted from child into observable that would be better.

Comment: You might want to use a service to handle the comms between child and parent. As you say create a subject on the service have your child update the data using its "next" method and subscribe in the parent or vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by using a ViewChild decorator.

```
<app-item-output #myChild></app-item-output>
```

```
@ViewChild('myChild') myChild: ItemOutputComponent;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.myChild.newItemEvent.subscribe(
    event => /** do something **/
  );
}
```

Try the described on stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-q9rcmk?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Yes in that case I do not need even '@output()' what you are doing in this way is taking the control from the child in the parent, but what i am more interested is in knowing any direct way using '@output()' without injecting the child instance in parent.

Comment: I could not find any other way to do it directly so going ahead with @MoxxiManagarm approach